# Defend Against CSRF with XSS in Viewstate

Tags: asp.net, xss, viewstate, csrf

I am doing some vulnerability testing for a website I am working on.  During the process of testing I found an issue with the site.  I created a small web form to submit data to the other web form and run some JavaScript. The small site can be viewed below:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="https://[URL]" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">
<type="hidden" select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCategory" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlCategory">
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="</span><script>alert(1);</script><span>" />
</div>
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

When I run click the submit button on this form I get an error on the web page stating:
"Invalid viewstate" but the JavaScript in the viewstate is still executed.

EnableEventValidation is set to true by default and is **not** being overridden by the web.config or the page.  How can I force the viewstate to be validated, but not execute the JavaScript?

Comment: Hmm...is `RequestValidation` turned off?

Comment: It was not modified in the page or web.config and by default it should be set to true.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with defending against CSRF or XSS in the form.  The problem was the error page printing out an unsanitized string of the viewstate after the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle error message in Application_Error method of Global.asax  with clearing the current error and showing custom response

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication httpApp = this.Context.ApplicationInstance;
    HttpException httpEx = httpApp.Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
    if (httpEx != null)
    {
        if (
            httpEx.WebEventCode == System.Web.Management.WebEventCodes.AuditInvalidViewStateFailure
            ||
            httpEx.WebEventCode == System.Web.Management.WebEventCodes.InvalidViewState
            ||
            httpEx.WebEventCode == System.Web.Management.WebEventCodes.InvalidViewStateMac
            ||
            httpEx.WebEventCode == System.Web.Management.WebEventCodes.RuntimeErrorViewStateFailure
            )
        {
            HttpContext.Current.ClearError();
            Response.Write("Error: Invalid viewstate has been detected (WebEventCode: " + httpEx.WebEventCode.ToString() + ").");
        }
    }
}
```